# Realm Studio - how to filter by linked objects

Tags: realm, realm-studio

When using Realm Studio, filtering by data columns on a collection works, however, filtering by a linked record does not seem to? I have tried both the syntax in the linked documentation as well as a variety of other attempts and guesses.

For example, my Schema has links to a "Component" object. I'd like to filter all the records that link to a specific Component. I have attempted the documented `component.id == 123` as well as many variations such as `component_id = 123`, `Component == $0, 123`, `componentId == [c] "123"`, and many more.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please include your two Realm object models so we can see what relationships you have set up. It also looks like the property you are filtering on is `component_id` not `componet.id`   ( _ not . ) so it should probably be `component_id.id == 891`

Comment: This appears to just be a typo so voting to close because of that. If there's more info, please update the question.